# How to calculate Precision ,Recall and F1 of specific target class in Orange?

Tags: orange

in Test & Score widget, we can change target class (if we do clasification).

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo7kN.png)

But i want to do Test & Score by using Python script widget.

> Orange.evaluation.Precision(results=None, **kwargs)
>
> Orange.evaluation.Recall(results=None, **kwargs)
>
> Orange.evaluation.F1(results=None, **kwargs)

How to change target class  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After obtaing CV (or other) results, for example with

```
import Orange
tree = Orange.classification.tree.TreeLearner()
res = Orange.evaluation.CrossValidation(data, [tree])
```

pass the target value index (see `data.domain.class_var.values`) to the scoring function:

```
Orange.evaluation.F1(res, target=0)
```

The classes F1, Recall, and Precision pass the arguments to the scikit-learn implementation.